W-2 + LLC + C Corp: Tax Strategy Question
I have a W-2 income and own an LLC (pass-through taxation) and a C Corporation (not pass-through). If my LLC pays my C Corporation for services rendered, will that lower my overall taxes by reducing my LLC + personal income which is taxed at ~38% but the tax rate for the C Corporation is lower at 20%?

Probably not, since if you want to use the money for yourself you'll need to extract it from the corporation.
Extracting money from a C-Corp can be done in two ways: either by drawing a salary (and then it's the same ordinary income tax bracket), or by drawing dividends.
If you draw the money as salary then you didn't save anything, and spent money on extra payroll and payroll taxes (FUTA/FICA/etc).
If you draw dividends then you'll pay the taxes twice: first the C-Corp will pay taxes (the 20% or whatever corp income tax you mentioned), and then you'll pay taxes on the dividend which can be either based on your marginal rates (which makes it even worse), or if qualified - based on capital gains rates, which makes it either break-even or worse - since you clearly don't fall into the 0% capital gains rate bracket.

Worth mentioning, IANAL, but if you do something like that - the validity of the transaction between your LLC and your C-Corp will undoubtedly be questioned as well.

For extracting money from the corporation can I not take a loan from the C-corp?

@PushpendreRastogi probably, but what's the point? You'll pay interest to the corporation, which will pay tax on it, and will repay the loan, and then what? As I mentioned in the footnote - whatever scheme you come up with, you wouldn't be the first. The IRS has seen it all and heard it all. And if you cross the line between benign ignorance and frivolous fraud - you can very much end up in prison. Ask some of these people.

I am trying to work out how feasible is it for an average joe to execute strategies such as "Borrow and Die" or "Move profits to low tax offshore jurisdictions" that more resourceful individuals and larger corporations do. [1] https://www.propublica.org/article/when-billionaires-dont-pay-taxes-people-lose-faith-in-democracy , and [2] https://news.bloombergtax.com/daily-tax-report/irss-28-9-billion-tax-claim-against-microsoft-explained . Regarding the repayment of loan, I think the strat is to refinance/renew the loan till one dies.

@PushpendreRastogi wealthy individuals have batteries of attorneys and accountants to structure this for them. Some will ask for a pre-determination from the IRS (PLR, costs $5000) to make sure the scheme won't be challenged, others will spend millions on litigation and will still lose (see the link in my previous comment).
